# Select nth h3 element of body

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select (for instance) the 2nd h3 element of my **body** without affecting the elements between them?

nth-of-type doesn't work because it will select the first parent!

Here's my jsfiddle (sorry because it's foreign and the code is not shortened)

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/tg7of5sp/>
```

Comment: No. It doesn't matter which child it is, as long as it's a h3. So i want the second h3 that's typed in the code

Comment: please share sample code with h3 element you want to selct as it is not obvious

Comment: You should clarify the question (by editiong the question). When you say nth-of-type does not work, you probably mean that you want to select (e.g.) the `h3` element that is the 2nd among all `h3` *descendants* of the `body` element, counted by order of appearance in source code.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks, that's what I meant. Im Sorry, not a natural english speaker.

Answer (score 3):

nth-of-type()

> The :nth-of-type(n) selector matches every element that is the nth
>   child, of a particular type, of its parent.n can be a number, a
>   keyword, or a formula.

[See Refrence](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

**Working Demo**  Selecting 2nd h3 of body

```css
body>h3:nth-of-type(2){
    color:red;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>1st Heading h3</h3>
  <div>
    
  <h3>div 1st Heading h3</h3>
   <h3>div 2nd Heading h3</h3>

    </div>
  
  <h3>2nd Heading h3</h3>
  </body>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only match h3's that are the 3rd element, of anything? Not the 3rd h3? Or am I getting nth-child all wrong? (Never used it much - I'll have to admit..)

Comment: Not working, the parent of each h3 element isn't the body, it's mostly a div. I want to select the second h3 that's in the body

Comment: thsese are different from array so 1 is equal to first child.. @FrederikSpang

Comment: Don't know why but it's not working.

Comment: I have updated the output ans css "now direct child of body will be selected if its h3 and second one"

Comment: but code is working here, may be any other problem? can you share your code

Comment: @someuseryoudontknowthenameof so you want to slect "Portfolio" one?